# Returning a list containing certain parameters from an array of json in PSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, jsonb

I am having some trouble figuring out on extracting a parameter (contactId) from a JSON list, and returning the extracted parameters in a list.

**Data**

Table Name: users

```
       contact
      -----------------------
1     {
       "mainContact": {
         name: "Timmy Tom",
         contactId: "11111"
         phoneNumber: "+12345"
      },
       "contactList": [
         {
          name: "Timmy Tom",
          contactId: "11111",
          phoneNumber: "+12345"
        },
        {
          name: "Robin Tom",
          contactId: "11112",
          phoneNumber: "+12345"
        },
        {
          name: "Jerry Tom",
          contactId: "11113",
          phoneNumber: "+12345"
        }
      ]
     }

2     {
       "mainContact": {
         name: "Timmy Bob",
         contactId: "21111"
         phoneNumber: "+12345"
      },
       "contactList": [
         {
          name: "Timmy Bob",
          contactId: "21111",
          phoneNumber: "+12345"
        },
        {
          name: "Robin Bob",
          contactId: "21112",
          phoneNumber: "+12345"
        },
        {
          name: "Jerry Bob",
          contactId: "21113",
          phoneNumber: "+12345"
        }
      ]
     }
```

I am able to filter the contactList out using the query:

```
SELECT contact -> 'contactList' as contact_list from users;
```

However, this is not what I need. I need to return the following response which only contains the contactId from the contactList in a JSON array but am unsure how to proceed further:

```
    contact_list
    ------------
1  [11111, 11112, 11113]
2. [21111, 21112, 21113]
```

Failed Attempts:

```
1. with query as (SELECT contact -> 'contactList' as contact_list from users)
select (contact_list ->> 'contactId') from query;
--> This query returns nothing, which I find puzzling
```

Would appreciate some guidance on this.. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a JSON path query:

```
select jsonb_path_query_array(contact, '$.contactList[*].contactId')
from users;
```

Comment: Nice. Didn't know this function

Comment: this function is great. Learned something new today. Thanks very much!

Answer (score 1):

First of all we use `jsonb_array_elements` function to unset jsonb array to rows and after that we  aggregate them using `string_agg`

```
with contactIds as (
    select 
        id, jsonb_array_elements(contact->'contactList')->>'contactId' as contact_list 
    from users
) select id, string_agg(contact_list, ',') from contactIds group by id;
```

[online sql editor](https://sqlize.online/sql/psql14/43eb33b5633315855400d95b3515154e/)

Comment: TIL about the jsonb_array_elements. Thanks very much!